# Passing a TFS Workspace object to c# code from Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, powershell, visual-studio-2013

I am currently working on creating Powershell scripts to create an easier to maintain build process in TFS 2013.

Part of this process requires a number of SQL compares to run with update scripts.

what I'm trying to do is use one of our old custom build activities (from TF 2010), which looked reasonably easy to convert to a c# code file for use within Powershell. 
This is needed as post build / pre unit test step.

I'd like to make the upgrades available to unit tests, some of which are DB based integration tests which were previously not upgrading until the following build.

the issue is is that my C# script requires a TFS Workspace, and i'm not sure how or where to instantiate this properly. The Build Activity was using TFS code model, which had InArguments as properties, and handled all of this.

I've changed this as below to run as a command like in the cut down C# example below:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.Activities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 

public class UpdateAndCheckinNewScripts
{
    Workspace workspace {get; set;}

    public UpdateAndCheckinNewScripts(Workspace workspace)
    {
         this.workspace = workspace; 
    }

    public void Execute(string versionToUpdate, string sourcesDirectory, string binariesDirectory)
    {
          //... do some stuff to scripts - ommitted...

          //Copy over previous script
           File.Copy(projectCreatefilePath, projectFinalPath, true);

          //Checkin Project Create Script
          workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(projectFinalPath), "Build Agent", "My checkin",  null, null, new PolicyOverrideInfo("Auto checkin", null),CheckinOptions.SuppressEvent);
    }

    private static void CheckinScript(string upgradeHolder,
            string filePath, string sourcesDirectory, string upgradeReplacementText, Workspace workspace)
        {
            string file = sourcesDirectory + @"\\yyy\xxx\Upgrade.csproj";

            //Checkout the project file <-- How do i create workspace to pass into  object? 
            workspace.PendEdit(file);

            workspace.PendAdd(filePath);
            // ... other code 
    }
}
```

I want to avoid an outright rewrite of this step if possible, but open to ideas. 
I wanted to move away from customising the default Xaml build definition in TFS 2013.
I'm taking some advice from this link as a starting point for using .net assemblies in Powershell:

http://ruudvanderlinden.com/2010/10/19/running-inline-c-with-custom-assemblies-in-powershell-2-0/

I want to know how i get the TFS workspace object for the current build into this, and how to instantiate.

i think the PS script might look something like this:

```
# assume I've run SQL comparison, create upgrade script and backups as needed....

# assuming all assembly and custom references required will have been added, here...

$tfWorkspace = ??? #not sure here
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source #assume $Source is the above c# source.
$scriptingobject = New-Object UpdateAndCheckinNewScripts($tfWorkspace)
$scriptingobject.Execute($buildVersion,$sourceLocalFolder,$binDirectory)

#continue with custom script...
```

i think i have 2 options:

1. instantiate the workspace object within the C# code somehow.
2. instantiate the object in PowerShell and pass to the instantiated
       object.

If anyone can help with me with either option, or any other idea, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok  - so i solved my issues in the end, with a bit of a learning curve. 

See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using powershell scripts, as mentioned by Microsoft development site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx .

I combined this with  TFS Power tools, and used the `Add-TfsPendingChange` and `New-TfsChangeset` cmdlets, but I also used the TFS API .Net objects where more control was needed.

I  did away with using our original custom Build activities, but we did customise the build definition, to allow more Powershell scripts to be called at more stages of the TFS 2013 standard template.

All I can say is that Powershell is extremely powerful and is worth the effort to learn, and it did pretty much all we needed for our build process.